# QPropertyAnimation doesn't animate

Tags: c++, qt, animation

This is my code:

```
void Widget::update()
{
    if (a==1)
    {
        QPushButton button("Animated Button");
        button.show();

        QPropertyAnimation *animation =
                    new QPropertyAnimation(&button, "geometry");
        animation->setDuration(10000);
        animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
        animation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

        animation->start();
        a++;
    }
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    a=1;
}
```

I am newbie in C++, how can I make this work?

Comment: How can you fix what? What doesn't work? What happens? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: there is nothing animation from pushbutton when i clicked it. i expect that when i clicked push button will be moved.
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read a good C++ book, or at the very least go though http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/.

For starters, you probably meant to call update() after a==1 in on_pushButton_clicked()? There is also a problem with your push button going out of scope at the end of the function, so you need to do

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Animated Button", this);
```

Finally, update() is a virtual function in QWidget (which I assume Widget derives?). Why are you overriding it? You probably want to call it something like startAnimatinon() instead.

Comment: i try to clicked on pushbutton but there is still no animate there.

i try to make simple animation to move button but i don't know where i can take my code there in mainwindow.cpp